# Trying to understand how to formulaically sum a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I thought this was as simple as calculating the area under the linear equation, but I get an answer that differs from the actual sum of values when I try.

I'm starting with a given number - 50,000 as an example and multiplying it by 0.995, and then taking that result and multiplying again by 0.995, and so on over 29 iterations (30 iterations if you consider the 50,000 an iteration). I want to sum of the results of each iteration. The formula for the iterations ought to be 50,000*(0.995^n) where n [0,30].

The area of said line, should be (I believe) 50,000 * 30 - (6,74.613 *30)/2, which is 1,398,531, but the actual sum is 1,396,158.

The subtracted portion is the triangle defined by the height: 50,000 - the value of the last iteration (43,235), multiplied by the base (30), divided by 2.

I'm missing something, right?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What does 6,74.613 mean?  Lines do not have area.  It's a geometric series with well know formulas for what you are asking.

Comment: The sum of your series is $50000\sum_{k=0}^{29} 0.995^k = 50000\,\frac{0.995^{29+1}-1}{0.995-1} = 1396158$ (rounded down to an integer). I don't understand what you're doing with the line and triangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, i solved the puzzle.
We consider the function $f$, given by $f(x) = 50\; 000\cdot 0.995^n$, for $n$ in $0,1,2,\dots,29$ and plot a bar diagram for it. There are many bars, the first one has the height $f(0) = 50\; 000$, the last one has the height $f(29)=43235.3865283767...$ and this differs from the fifty T by $67\color{red}{6}4.61347162332...$ , so we may try to **approximate** the sum
$$
\sum_{0\le n< 30}S\; r^n=S\frac{1-r^{30}}{1-r}\ ,\qquad S=50\; 000\ ,\ r=0.995\ ,
$$
seen as the "area of the many bars of width one" with the area of the figure obtained by assuming that the bars are "aligned", so that exactly one triangle is missing from the rectangle with height $S=50\; 000$, and width $30$. Well, this is not the case, we have **exponential** decay, not linear decay, the exact result is thus, using a "calculator" (here [sage](https://www.sagemath.org))

```
sage: S, r = 50000, 0.995
sage: sum( [ S*r^n for n in [0..29] ] )
1.39615808085304e6
sage: S*(1-r^30)/(1-r)
1.39615808085304e6
```

To see the difference, let us take $r=0.95$ instead, and raw-plot the function...

```
? plot( n=0, 29, 50000 * 0.95^n )

    50000 "_'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''|
          | x                                                            |
          |  "_                                                          |
          |    "_                                                        |
          |      x_                                                      |
          |        x                                                     |
          |         "x                                                   |
          |           "x                                                 |
          |             "x_                                              |
          |                x_                                            |
          |                  "_                                          |
          |                    "x_                                       |
          |                       "x                                     |
          |                         "x_                                  |
          |                            "x_                               |
          |                               ""x_                           |
          |                                   "x_                        |
          |                                      ""x_                    |
          |                                          ""x__               |
          |                                               "xx__          |
          |                                                    "xx__     |
11296.777 |.........................................................""xx__
          0                                                             29
?
```

Here we expect a bigger difference between the exponential decay and the linear decay...

Comment: Thanks! I was missing something - I didn't think it thru and trusted the linear looking graph in excel that it was a linear decay. Of course it's exponential.